# Transfer files from a shared folder of a cloud to a non shared folder of another cloud

Tags: cloud-storage, google-drive, data-transfer, cloud

I'm wondering if there is a way to move files from a shared folder of a cloud to a non shared folder of another cloud without download them. So far I found only solutions which allow to transfer file between non shared folders of different clouds (e. g. air explorer).

I am not the owner of the shared folder.

---

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10 and I'm looking for a free solution. The clouds I'm interesting in are OneDrive, Google Drive, Mega.